# Find Flickr username if ID is provided?

Tags: python, flickr

Is there an API call or some other way to find username of a Flickr account If I have user id of that account ?

Answer (score 1):

The [flickr.people.getInfo](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.getInfo.html) call will suit your needs.